# debugging emacs freezing in adoc-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I work a lot with Asciidoc in emacs (`adoc-mode`). I believe it has a bug that occurs when editing inlined source code. What happens is emacs freezes, CPU consumption goes to 100%. I can reproduce this behaviour easily.

How do I actually establish what script is causing emacs to hang like that?? And preferably produce a backtrace?

Since emacs freezes while *typing within the buffer*, rather than after executing a command, stuff like
 `toggle-debug-on-quit` or `debug-on-entry` are useless.

I suppose I could mark every single `defun` in `adoc-mode.el` with `printf`s, but I'm hoping there's an easier way :)

**EDIT:**
So, I ended up `grep`ping my `~/.emacs.d/lisp` for ALL `defun`s and `trace-function` each one.
I was able to narrow down the problem and created a small test case.

These 3 files are required:

```
$ find /home/victor/.emacs.d/
/home/victor/.emacs.d/
/home/victor/.emacs.d/lisp
/home/victor/.emacs.d/lisp/doc-mode.el
/home/victor/.emacs.d/lisp/adoc-mode.el
/home/victor/.emacs.d/lisp/markup-faces.el
```

My `.emacs`:

```
$ cat .emacs
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
(require 'adoc-mode)
(switch-to-buffer (find-file "test.doc"))
(adoc-mode)
(goto-char 29)
(delete-backward-char 5)
;; now (adoc-kwf-attriblist) is in endless loop!!
```

And the testcase is (word "shell" is deleted by elisp):

```
$ cat test.doc 
blah blah blah
[source,shell]
foo
bar
```

Now, run `emacs` and it will hang in `(adoc-kwf-attriblist)`. I don't know much about emacs programming, but seems this thing does not eventually move the point to `end` position.

```
 (goto-char (or (text-property-not-all (point) end 'adoc-attribute-list nil)
             end))
```

Comment: when emacs freezes, can you interrupt it with `C-g`?

Comment: @Francesco: when emacs freezes, it can't be interrupted by \C-g\. Emacs just stays there hanging, not responding events (typing, clicking to close window, etc).

Comment: You are correct -- there is an assumption that if text-property-not-all returns, it returns something greater than point. Unfortunately, it can return the same as point, and so it loops. I've put a fix on github

Answer (score 1):

debug-on-entry might help, if you can identify a function in the sequence that reaches the looper.

Have you tried "apropos" "debug"?

Not sure about debug-on-signal or debug-on-quit.  If using Unix "kill" or Windows Task Manager "End Task" sends a signal to emacs, you might intercept it with debug-on-signal.

And search for "debug loop" at
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gnu.emacs.help

Also, you could compile some functins in adoc-mode.el "debug" with edebug-defun.

(I hope I haven't fuddled this topic.  I'm new here, and not familiar with "Answer" vs "Comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would debug it. The freezing might be happening because of some minor mode. You can do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to get a list to the minor modes active. Then start emacs with `emacs -Q` and load `adoc-mode`, then load each of the minor modes one by one each time trying to reproduce the issue. This may lead you to the culprit.

Comment: I did this. Starting with `emacs -Q`, loading manually the files defining `adoc-mode` (namely `adoc-mode.el` and `markup-faces.el`). The list of enabled minor mode was different (some more, some less). The bug still appeared without manually loading more minor mode.